# How do I form a query with a running count retaining the order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a trace table which looks like this

[image: TraceTable]

I'd like to get a running total which looks like the following output - its very important that I retain the order - as this is the execution order of the stored porcedures - It will help me analyze bottle necks in the system

[image: Output]

I have tried

```
select max(RowNumber),objectname, count(1) from rob
where eventclass = 42
group by objectname
```

But that mucks up the order

Is this even possible in SQL?

UPDATE:
I tried this

```
select RowNumber,objectname, count(1) from rob
where eventclass = 42
group by objectname,RowNumber
order by RowNumber
```

But this (as the query quite rightly says groups by rownumber (have to have that to have it in the order by) )

Comment: There is no order unless explicitly specified. It is [maya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_%28illusion%29).

Comment: The order is the rownumber from the origanal table - I have updated the question with a query that has the order by part

Comment: Do you want to compact trace table by counting adjacent (by rownumber) records having the same objectname? If so, which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: +1 yeh thats kind of what im after the answer below is perfect - I have SQL 2005 profiler but a 2008 express version of the database :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select objectname, 
       count(*)
from (
     select RowNumber,
            objectname,
            row_number() over(order by RowNumber) - row_number() over(order by objectname, RowNumber) as grp
     from rob
     where eventclass = 42
     ) as T
group by grp, objectname
order by min(RowNumber)
```

Working sample using a table variable.

```
declare @T table
(
  RowNumber int,
  objectname varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values
(8, 'f_system_log_init'),
(10, 'f_purge_system_log'),
(25, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(65, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(104, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(143, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(182, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(221, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(5015, 'f_get_system_logs_parent_log_id_for_dataloader'),
(5055, 'f_system_log_msg'),
(5096, 'f_system_log_msg')

select objectname, 
       count(*)
from (
     select RowNumber,
            objectname,
            row_number() over(order by RowNumber) - row_number() over(order by objectname, RowNumber) as grp
     from @T
     ) as T
group by grp, objectname
order by min(RowNumber)
```

Result:

```
objectname                                         
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
f_system_log_init                                  1
f_purge_system_log                                 1
f_system_log_msg                                   6
f_get_system_logs_parent_log_id_for_dataloader     1
f_system_log_msg                                   2
```

Comment: The other +1 was mine - and to think that I was thinking about self-join :-( Thank you for this brilliant idea. Gaps and islands will never be same again ;-)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I can not take credit for this technique. It is described on page 68 in [SQL Server MVP Deep Dives- Chapter 5 Gaps and Islands](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf) by Itzik Ben-Gan.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by rownumber,objectname) rn from test101)

,CTE1 as(
select *,1 as incr from CTE where rn=1 
union all
select t.*,
CASE WHEN t.objectname=c.objectname then incr else incr+1 end  as incr
from CTE t inner join CTE1 c
on t.rn=c.rn+1
)

select max(objectname),count(incr) from CTE1
group by incr
```