# SQL Server - How to group rows in a series by the most recent change in a value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that logs sessions and events. The event table includes timestamps and usernames. A user might be anonymous or log in as many different users during any given session.

I am trying to create a log in session identifier based on event timestamps and when the username changes. I can order the events based on timestamp and I can see when the username changes, but I cannot figure out how to associate every event row with its respective "log in session" that identifies the most recent event when the username changed.

I've created this example that models what I need to do. `a.ord` is an ordinal in an unbroken series and `a.val` is a value. `b.pval` is the preceding value in the series.

```
with a as (
    select 1 AS ord, 'abc' as val union
    select 2, 'xyz' union
    select 3, 'abc' union
    select 4, 'abc' union
    select 5, 'xyz' union
    select 6, 'xyz' union
            select 7, 'xyz'
),
b as (
    select
        a1.ord as ord,
        a1.val as val,
        a2.val as pval
    from a a1
    left join a a2 on a1.ord - 1 = a2.ord 
    where a1.val != isnull(a2.val, '')
)
select
    *
from b
```

The above code returns the rows where the value changes, including the first row when the value changes from null to "abc". This is what is returned:

```
ORD VAL PVAL
1   abc NULL
2   xyz abc
3   abc xyz
5   xyz abc
```

I need to somehow return `a left join b` so that it returns the following, where "ORD" is a.ord, "VAL" is a.val and "CHG" is b.ord.

```
ORD VAL CHG
1   abc 1
2   xyz 2
3   abc 3
4   abc 3
5   xyz 5
6   xyz 5
7   xyz 5
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Itzik Ben-Gan's solution to islands and gaps (presented to me by Mikael Eriksson [by answering to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842652/1231866)) it becomes quite simple. `grouped` retrieves all the records from `a` augmented by column `grp` holding a number which remains the same as two sequences go along. Combination of this number and `val` is unique. In main query one selects min(ord) grouped by this two values.

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4251).

```
; with a as (
    select 1 AS ord, 'abc' as val union all
    select 2, 'xyz' union all
    select 3, 'abc' union all
    select 4, 'abc' union all
    select 5, 'xyz' union all
    select 6, 'xyz' union all
    select 7, 'xyz'
),
grouped as (
    select *,
           row_number() over (order by ord)
         - row_number() over (order by val, ord) grp
      from a
)
select ord, 
       val, 
       min(ord) over(partition by grp, val) chg
  from grouped
 order by ord
```

[And some reading material](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf).

Comment: This works and is reasonably fast. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for using min(x) over(partition by y) instead of a grouped subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while attempting to write a readable title for the question.

The answer is the following:

```
with a as (
    select 1 AS ord, 'abc' as val union
    select 2, 'xyz' union
    select 3, 'abc' union
    select 4, 'abc' union
    select 5, 'xyz' union
    select 6, 'xyz' union
    select 7, 'xyz'
),
b as (
    select
        a1.ord ord,
        a1.val val,
        a2.val sval
    from a a1
    left join a a2 on a1.ord - 1 = a2.ord 
    where a1.val != isnull(a2.val, '')
)
select
    *
from a
outer apply (
    select
        MAX(ord) as chg
    from b
    where a.val = b.val
    and a.ord >= b.ord
) x
```

Comment: My solution works, but is incredibly slow on my larger dataset.